# how to make this card design in flutter with help of stack

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Being a beginner in learning a Flutter, I still find it difficult to implement a lot of designs and learn them online, but this design after a long search, I did not find any example similar. I wish I could find help in making this design

[image]

Comment: you want the card that show the green text?

Comment: Thank you for your interest , no i want it with the background image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
class MyApp11 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}



class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          // background image and bottom contents
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Background image goes here'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Content goes here'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          // Profile image
          Positioned(
            top: 200.0, // (background container size) - (circle height / 2)
            child: Container(
              height: 130.0,
              width: 200.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the card that show on page you can use this code:

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
          spreadRadius: 0,
          blurRadius: 7,
          offset: Offset(0, 8),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.location_on),
              Text('Some location'),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 16),
            child: Text(
              '800,000 KWD',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]